# Angular 7 html data binging i data-count

Tags: angular

I need to bind data to HTML element i:

```
<i data-count="{{notificationsLength}}" class="fas fa-bell notification-icon" aria-label="Nofitication centre"></i>
```

I get error message: Can't bind to 'count' since it isn't a known property of 'i'.

Then I tried:

```
<i (data-count)="{{notificationsLength}}" class="fas fa-bell notification-icon" aria-label="Nofitication centre"></i>
```

but with the same result.

Thanks for help.

Comment: why and what exactly you want to do? can bind only properties known to tag

Comment: Did my answer help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[attr.*]` syntax (without curly braces).

```
<i [attr.data-count]="notificationsLength" class="fas fa-bell notification-icon" aria-label="Nofitication centre"></i>
```

For further reading:

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-class-and-style-bindings

Answer (score 0):

**Use attribute binding syntax instead**

```
<i  [attr.data-count]="notificationsLength" class="fas fa-bell notification-icon" aria-label="Nofitication centre"></i>
```

**You can also use it this way**

```
<i  attr.data-count="{{notificationsLength}}" class="fas fa-bell notification-icon" aria-label="Nofitication centre"></i>
```